# What pin does the pySerial interrupt when running?

Tags: python, arduino, pyserial

Since [pySerial](http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/) is a serial communication technique, will it then be interrupting a pin on the Arduino board once there is some data to be given to the Arduino board?

Which pin does it interrupt to run the [ISR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrupt_handler)? Or is it using a polling method?
Am I understanding the concept right?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Send serial bytes to your Arduino?

Answer (score 0):

pySerial gives access to UART hardware.  Reading/writing data doesn't involve any interrupts.  You just call read() and write().  read() will block until data is available, with an optional timeout.

Answer (score 0):

On the Arduino board, serial communication usually occurs over the UART, which uses digital pins 0 and 1. The UART is a physical peripheral on the ATmega328P microcontroller that has its own interrupts, `UDRE`, so you are not using any of the regular or pin change interrupts otherwise available. This interrupt is triggered whenever a full byte has been received. There is also a separate `TX` interrupt available which signals that a byte has been transmitted.